# How do you just use a DBContext in dotnet Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

So lets say I just make a helper class and need to call the DB from inside a Static Method.

```
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 
'options' of 'ApplicationDbContext.ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<‌​
ApplicationDbContext‌​>)'
```

I can't seem to just do

```
    public static bool IsKeyValid(string key)
    {
        var isValid = false;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(key)) {
            isValid = new ApplicationDbContext().Children.Any(x => x.Token == key);
        }

        return isValid;
    }
```

So I know I can get my context from my controller and pass it in, but is that the only way?

I'm very confused because all the docs just kinda say "Hey, make a new context, look how easy it is"
http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/querying/basic.html#id3

Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: any errors or exceptions ?

Comment: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'options' of 'ApplicationDbContext.ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to create the context manually, then you can configure it as shown below.

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionStringSecureValue("DefaultConnection"));
_context = new ApplicationDbContext(options.Options);
```

Please see this too : [**Configuring a DbContext**](http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext.html)

Comment: Why does it have to be so obnoxiously verbose?  Is this literally the only way to grab it?

Comment: How do you get an instance of "Configuration" in that sample though?  I see it available in the Startup.cs as an IConfiguratiionRoot, but I cant seem to get it though just pasting that code into a helper.

Inital thought is to wrap this into a parameterless constructor on ApplicationDbContext yeah?

Comment: I'm marking it as the answer, but I feel like this is just so not a step forward

Comment: That is the way it has been designed.But if you want you can use `repository pattern`,`generic repository` and etc..